# how to select a specific value from the <option value> in <select> tag in a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a **Select** tag that includes in the *option tag*   **3 values**

```
<option value = '".$row ->ownerID.", ".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
```

example: 161, 3,Burj El Brajneh

i need in the SQL query to just compare the third element.

tables:

1. site_info:

   ```
   siteID

   siteNAME

   ownerID

   companyID
   ```
2. owner_info:

   ```
   ownerID

   ownerNAME
   ```
3. company_info:

   ```
   companyID

   companyNAME
   ```

## select tag:

```
             <?php


                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME, ownerID, companyID  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                  {
                   echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID.", ".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                  } 

             ?>

            </select></td>
```

## php check:

```
if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];

          }
          else { $site_name=""; }
```

in order to select the third element as i want i added to the SQL query  this statement **$site_name->siteNAME**    but it seems not working

if i write just $site_name in the query the result will be:

**site_name='161, 3,Burj El Brajneh'**

[image]

## SQL query:

```
 $sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
         , i.siteNAME
         , i.equipmentTYPE
         , c.latitude
         , c.longitude
         , c.height 
         , o.ownerNAME
         , o.ownerCONTACT
         , x.companyNAME
         , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
         , y.subcontractorNAME
         , y.subcontractorCONTACT
      from site_info i
      LEFT  
      JOIN owner_info o
        on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
      LEFT  
      JOIN company_info x
        on i.companyID = x.companyID
      LEFT 
      JOIN subcontractor_info y
        on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
        LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
        on i.siteID=c.siteID 
        where 
        i.siteNAME = %s
        AND 
        o.ownerNAME = %s
        AND 
        x.companyNAME = %s
       ",$site_name->siteNAME,$owner_name,$company_name);

     $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this in php

```
IF ($row[$i]['abc'] == 'A'){
$a[$i]='<option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>';
$b[$i]='<option value="B" >B</option>';
}
IF ($row[$i]['abc'] == 'B'){
$a[$i]='<option value="A" >A</option>';
$b[$i]='<option value="B" selected="selected" B</option>';
}
```

in html

```
<select>
    <php? echo $a[$i]; ?>
    <php? echo $b[$i]; ?>
 </select>
```

you just check if the value is same then echo it as selected="selected"

and your if statement question

```
if (empty($_POST["site_name"])) {
        $site_name='';
        }
           else {
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
           }
```

Comment: i did not understand your answer how to use it in my code  because its always will be  **===A** .
i tried to add  **selected="selected"** to the option tag  but it did not work